# Sum of tagged lines perl/shellscript

Tags: perl, sum, shell

I have input that looks like

```
5 X
8 Y
3 Z
9 X
```

I want output that sums the numerical values for each 'tag'; e.g.

```
14 X
8 Y
3 Z
```

Wondering if there is a slick one liner I can use (along the lines of the ones for summing a list of integers using awk).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
perl -ne '$table{$2} += $1 if /(\d+)\s+(.+)/; END {print "$table{$_} $_\n" for keys %table}'
```

or to use auto-splitting:

```
perl -ane '$table{$F[1] or next} += $F[0]; END {print "$table{$_} $_\n" for keys %table}'
```

Comment: You're missing the `-n` flag to loop over all input. (Nice FGITW, BTW) :)

Answer (score 0):

As slick as I can make it:

```
perl -alne 'END{print"$X{$_} $_"for sort{$X{$b}<=>$X{$a}}keys%X}$X{$F[1]}+=$F[0]'
```

Comment: it looks like you are having trouble with your space key :)

Answer (score 0):

Tried to make it as little obfuscated as possible :)
Sorts output by 'tag'.

`perl -alne '$counts{$F[1]} += $F[0]; END { print "$counts{$_} $_" for sort(keys %counts) }'`

Answer (score 0):

Output in random order

```
perl -alne'$t{$F[1]}+=$F[0]}{print"$t{$_} $_"for keys%t'
```

alphabetically sorted by tag

```
perl -alne'$t{$F[1]}+=$F[0]}{print"$t{$_} $_"for sort keys%t'
```

sorted by value

```
perl -alne'$t{$F[1]}+=$F[0]}{print"$t{$_} $_"for sort{$t{$b}<=>$t{$a}}keys%t'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk "{count[$2]+=$1}END{for(i  in count)print count[i],i}" 1.t
```